# Typescript React: How to declare types for specific element which is Props

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types

I want to declare types for specific element something like `<button>` or `<input>`.
but, I can't check specific element with type

Heres example,

```js
interface Props{
  component: React.ComponentProps<"button"> | never;
};

const TestComponent = (props: Props) =>{
  const {component} = props;
  return <div>{component}</div>
}

const OnlyButtonComponent = () => {
  return(
    <>
      {/** This will be Okay. */}
      <TestComponent component={<button>its button</button>} />
      {/** This must occur error */}
      <TestComponent component={<div>its not button</div>} />
    </>
  )
}
```

BUT, both of `TestComponent` is rendered with no errors.

How i can guard this with type declare?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
interface Props{
  component: React.ReactNode
};
```

Comment: hi, Thats not what I exactly want. I mean `SPECIFIC` elements.
In this case I want only `<button>` elements. not All React Nodes.